# use insert value as trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

is it possible to use the insert value in the where clause in SQL?

I would want to use it in this kinda way:

```
create trigger t_wage_not_higher_than_30000
on transaction
as
if exists
(
select * 
from transaction
where ***inserted value*** >= 30000 and
description = employeewage
)
begin
raiserror('you cannot insert a wage higher than 30000')
rollback transaction
end
```

Comment: An `INSERT` statement can insert more than one row, and the rows to be inserted are present in the pseudo-table [`inserted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables). Note that if a condition should apply to in all cases and not merely for newly inserted rows, a `CHECK` constraint is more appropriate than a trigger.

Comment: You are generating error after insert i guess, you will need to raise error before insert. Can be achieved in a stored proc

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the range of values, the best way is to use a check constraint:

```
alter table transactions add constraint chk_transactions_value
    check (value < 30000);
```

There is no reason to write a trigger for checking data values.

Comment: well, this table is not only for adding wage. thats why i use the where description = employeewage. It is also used for bigger transactions which can be higher than 30000. i would like to only trigger when the description is employeewage

Comment: @MFox: then you can simply add that to the `CHECK` constraint. `if a then b` is logically equivalen to `not a or b`, so `check (description <> 'employeewage' or value < 30000)`. Any constraint based only on the values of the columns in one single row can be written as a `CHECK`, which is superior to a trigger even if the checks are harder to read. A trigger is necessary only when the constraint cross-references rows or otherwise depends on the state of the entire table somehow, like "not exceeding the current average".

Comment: @MFox . . . Then you would adjust the logic to be what you want.  It would be similar if you had a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

For this trigger, you should only refer to the newly inserted rows. Therefore, you need to use the special trigger table in your statement. E.g.,

```
if exists (select * from inserted 
    where <some column you did not name in 
    your code> >= 30000 and description = 'employeewage') 
begin 
   raiserror ... (or throw);
   rollback tran;
   return;
end;
```

And yes - a constraint is generally a better approach.